# How to scale thousands of Firebase app instances

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, firebase-admin

I need to initialize potentially thousands of Firebase app instances server-side using `firebase-admin` with a service account and then listen to specific Realtime DB and Firestore events on these app instances. These instances have nothing to do with one another and the only access I have to them is through their service account credentials files.

My main concern is scaling because new project app instances will be initialized on the fly. It is important that the events listened to should not be duplicated, so I can not have multiple server instances initialize listen to the events of all the apps.

Ideally, I would love to have an auto-scaling serverless solution and to keep it inside the Google Cloud Platform family. If there was a way to work with the app instances, while they are auto-scaled behind the scenes - like a load balancer for a collection of app instances. I've looked at the Google Cloud Pub/Sub solution to potentially do something like this, but could not come up with something concrete.

The non-scaling solution I have so far, using cloud functions:

**EDIT: After feedback regarding Cloud Functions**

- <s>on startup of my project's cloud functions, initialize all the current app instances</s>
- <s>have a cloud function listen to newly added service accounts and initialize a new app instance for it. Currently, I have no idea how many project instances I can keep in memory before it becomes a problem.</s>

Start up a single Node server to initialize all the current app instances. As new projects are added, simply add a reference for it. Monitor the server closely to ensure it doesn't run out of memory. Scale vertically as far as possible. When it gets to the point where necessary, start up a second server instance, but manually distribute project instances between servers, so there are no duplicates.

> **Bonus question:** are only the individual cloud functions scaled as needed? ie. what happens to other standard JS functions/objects created outside a cloud function but inside the cloud functions `index.js` file?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Happy to elaborate on anything.

Comment: This seems a bit like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You're telling me you need to initialize thousands of Firebase app instances, but let's start with *why* you need to do that. What is the broader goal you're trying to accomplish? We can probably help more if we know :)

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for taking a look, @MichaelBleigh. We are building a CMS on top of Firebase, which allows users to hook up their Firebase projects to our interface. We want to add "webhooks" functionality when certain events happen within the app. The payload for these events is written to the user's own Firebase DB because we don't want to open our API up to everyone from anywhere. I want to listen for these webhook entries written to their DBs and then process them server-side. Hope that makes sense.